# unexpected dots before api output

Tags: php, json, rest, swagger

I am working for rest api with php . following https://github.com/mevdschee/php-crud-api

It works fine for localhost on local pc but when i upload it to server then following unexpected characters in front of the response shown .

Any Solution ? Thanks

```
 {"sccoin_atm":{"columns":["atm_id","operator_id","atm_service","atm_country","atm_city","atm_state","atm_zipcode","atm_latitude","atm_longitude","atm_address","atm_image","atm_location_name","atm_location_phone","atm_location_website","atm_location_type","atm_open_hours","atm_manufacturer","atm_model","atm_buy","atm_sell","atm_buy_markup","atm_buy_feed","atm_sell_markdown","atm_sell_feed","atm_limits","atm_serial_number","atm_cryptocurrencies","atm_reference_link","atm_extra_description","atm_verifications","atm_date_added","atm_feature","atm_online","atm_warn","atm_meta_title","atm_meta_keyword","atm_meta_desc","atm_status","atm_create_date","atm_update_date"],"records":[[15,16,"ATM","3","295","",32443,"41.86637910","-87.71073690","3400 W Roosevelt Rd\r\nChicago, IL 60624\r\nUSA ","img-1.jpg","Star Gyro","314231","ddd.com","21","324","22","19","Yes","No","sad","","szad","","dd","ddddsdf","Bitcoin, Ether, ","dfds","
    zdfsd<\/p> ","

    sdfsdf<\/p> ","2011-08-19","","","No","sdfsdf","zdsfs","zdzsf","Active","2017-04-02","0000-00-00"],[16,16,"ATM","3","295","",32443,"41.75108980","-87.60487950","3400 W Roosevelt Rd\r\nChicago, IL 60624\r\nUSA ","img-8.jpg","Happy Liquor and Food","314231","ddd.com","21","324","22","19","Yes","No","sad","","szad","","dd","ddddsdf","Bitcoin, Ether, ","dfds","
```

Comment: magic_quotes on in php config maybe?

Comment: What PHP versions are you using on your local machine and on the server? (The suggested magic quotes was deprecated in php 5.3 and totally removed in php 5.4, which both are _really_ old and unsupported versions).

Comment: Current PHP version: 7.0.17 on server and Current PHP version: 7.1.1 local

Comment: Did you scan the code for that character sequence?